# Replacing second row of each group with first row of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'sym': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
        'open': [99, 22, 34, 63, 75, 86, 1800, 82],
        'high': [3987, 41123, 46123, 6643, 75, 3745, 72123, 74],
        'x': ['gd', 'ed', 'we', 'vt', 'de', 'sw', 'ee', 'et'],

    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'sym': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
        'open': [77, 232, 434, 33, 55, 66, 1000],
        'high': [177, 11123, 1123, 343, 55, 3545, 21323],
        'x': ['g', 'e', 'w', 'v', 'd', 's', 'g'],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
  sym  open   high   x
0   a    99   3987  gd
1   a    77   177   ed
2   a    34  46123  we
3   a    63   6643  vt
4   b    75     75  de
5   b   434   1123  sw
6   b  1800  72123  ee
7   c    82     74  et
```

These are the steps needed. Groups are defined by `sym`:

a) Select the first row of each group in `df2`

b) Only `open` and `high` is needed for the previous step.

c) Replace these values with the values from the second row of each group in `df1`.

So for example for group `a`:

a) `df2`: row `0` is selected

b) `df2`: `open` is 77 and `high` is 177

c) from row `1` of `df1` 22 and 41123 are replaced with 77 and 177.

This is what I have tried. It gives me an `IndexError`. But even if it does not give me that error, it feels like this is not the way:

```
def replace_second_row(df):
    selected_sym = df.sym.iloc[0]
    row = df2.loc[df2.sym == selected_sym]
    row = row[['open', 'high']].iloc[0]
    df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('open'): df.columns.get_loc('open') + 2] = row
    return df


output = df1.groupby('sym').apply(replace_second_row)
```

The traceback of above`IndexError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\py_files\example_df.py", line 1618, in <module>
    x = df1.groupby('sym').apply(replace_second_row)
  File "C:\Users\AF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 894, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f, self._selected_obj)
  File "C:\Users\AF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 928, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, data, self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\AF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 238, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "D:\python\py_files\example_df.py", line 1614, in replace_second_row
    df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('open'): df.columns.get_loc('open') + 2] = row
  File "C:\Users\AF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 689, in __setitem__
    self._has_valid_setitem_indexer(key)
  File "C:\Users\AF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1401, in _has_valid_setitem_indexer
    raise IndexError("iloc cannot enlarge its target object")
IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object
```

For more clarification of the process, I have uploaded an image. The highlighted rows are the rows that are needed to be selected/changed.

[image]

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas I didn't put the traceback because I feel that my approach is not correct. So that is why.

Comment: if you have error then you should show it - it helps to see which line makes problem, and it shows what is the problem in this line. We can try to fix your code to see if your idea is useful.

Comment: you mention `"group"` - do you means group by `sym`? maybe you could use `df2.groupby('sym')` for this? And get first elements from every group `df2.groupby('sym').first()` and second probably with `df1.groupby('sym')[1]`

Comment: maybe in `iloc` you should use `+1` instead of `+2` - and this could fix error.

Comment: this works for me `df[['open', 'high']].iloc[1] = row[['open', 'high']].iloc[0]` but code has to check length of group because group `c` has only one row.

Comment: @furas Yes. That is why I felt this solution may not be the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

df1, df2 `set_index` & make `cc` column

```
tmp1 = df1.assign(cc=df1.groupby('sym').cumcount()).set_index(['sym', 'cc'])
tmp2 = df2.groupby('sym').head(1).assign(cc=1).set_index(['sym', 'cc'])\
          .drop('x', axis=1)
```

tmp1

```
        open    high    x
sym cc          
a   0   99      3987    gd
    1   22      41123   ed
    2   34      46123   we
    3   63      6643    vt
b   0   75      75      de
    1   86      3745    sw
    2   1800    72123   ee
c   0   82      74      et
```

tmp2(only 1st row of df2 group, and make cc column to 1 [means 2nd row] & remove x column):

```
        open    high
sym cc      
a   1   77      177
b   1   434     1123
c   1   55      55
```

---

use `combine_first` tmp2 & tmp1

```
out = tmp2[tmp2.index.isin(tmp1.index)].combine_first(tmp1)\
          .reindex_like(tmp1).reset_index().drop('cc', axis=1)
```

out:

```
  sym   open    high    x
0   a   99      3987    gd
1   a   77      177     ed
2   a   34      46123   we
3   a   63      6643    vt
4   b   75      75      de
5   b   434     1123    sw
6   b   1800    72123   ee
7   c   82      74      et
```

The boolean indexing used to create `out` removes the values of c in tmp2 that do not have a second row in tmp1.

Answer (score 2):

pandas index alignment helps here - create unique rows from df2 with the second rows per group, and use these values to replace df1 with the the `where` method - index aligment occurs after we set `sym` as the index on both dataframes:

```py
A=df1.set_index('sym')
B=df2.set_index('sym')
# get first rows per group
B=B.loc[B.groupby('sym').cumcount().eq(0), ['open','high']]
# this works well because of automatic index alignment
A=A.loc[:, ['open','high']].where(A.groupby('sym').cumcount().ne(1),B)
A=A.reset_index()
df1.assign(**A)
  sym  open   high   x
0   a    99   3987  gd
1   a    77    177  ed
2   a    34  46123  we
3   a    63   6643  vt
4   b    75     75  de
5   b   434   1123  sw
6   b  1800  72123  ee
7   c    82     74  et
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code I had to use `loc` instead of `iloc` to replace values,
so I used `df.index[0]` instead `1`.

I found that I can `df.name` instead of `selected_sym = df.sym.iloc[0]`

Because sym `c` has only one row so I used `len(df) > 1` to skip it

```
def replace_second_row(df):
    if len(df) > 1:
        df1_index = df.index[1]
        row = df2[df2.sym == df.name].iloc[0]
        df.loc[df1_index, ['open', 'high']] = row[['open', 'high']]
    return df
```

The same little different - maybe more readable

```
def replace_second_row(df):
    if len(df) > 1:
        df1_index = df.index[1]
        df2_index = df2[df2.sym == df.name].index[0]
        df.loc[df1_index, ['open', 'high']] = df2.loc[df2_index, ['open', 'high']]
    return df
```

You can also use `df2.groupby('sym').first()` to reduce number of rows

```
df_first = df2.groupby('sym').first().reset_index()

def replace_second_row(df):
    if len(df) > 1:
        df1_index = df.index[1]
        df2_index = df_first[df_first.sym == df.name].index[0]
        df.loc[df1_index, ['open', 'high']] = df2.loc[df2_index, ['open', 'high']]
    return df
```

---

Full working code - so everyone can simply copy and test it.

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sym': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    'open': [99, 22, 34, 63, 75, 86, 1800, 82],
    'high': [3987, 41123, 46123, 6643, 75, 3745, 72123, 74],
    'x': ['gd', 'ed', 'we', 'vt', 'de', 'sw', 'ee', 'et'],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sym': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'open': [77, 232, 434, 33, 55, 66, 1000],
    'high': [177, 11123, 1123, 343, 55, 3545, 21323],
    'x': ['g', 'e', 'w', 'v', 'd', 's', 'g'],
})

#df_first = df2.groupby('sym').first().reset_index()
#print(df_first)

def replace_second_row(df):
    if len(df) > 1:
        df1_index = df.index[1]
        df2_index = df2[df2.sym == df.name].index[0]
        #df2_index = df_first[df_first.sym == df.name].index[0]
        df.loc[df1_index, ['open', 'high']] = df2.loc[df2_index, ['open', 'high']]
        #row = df2[df2.sym == df.name].iloc[0]
        #df.loc[df1_index, ['open', 'high']] = row[['open', 'high']]
    return df

output = df1.groupby('sym', group_keys=False).apply(replace_second_row)
print(output)
```